# How to use OR operator in filter data with **kwargs?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this:

```
excl = dict()

kwargs['field1__isnull'] = False
kwargs['field2__isnull'] = False
kwargs['field3__isnull'] = False

items = MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs).exclude(**excl)
```

And it generates this SQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM `mytable` WHERE (`field1` IS NULL  AND `field2` IS NULL AND `field2` IS NULL)
```

But I want this:

```
SELECT ... FROM `mytable` WHERE (`field1` IS NULL  AND `field2` IS NULL OR `field2` IS NULL)
```

How to do it (I must use kwargs dictionary, unless it can be combined with Q)?

Comment: Would not it be `filed1 IS NOT NULL AND` instead `filed1 IS NULL  AND ` ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming danihp is correct with his question, I think you'd want something like this:

```
excl = dict()

f = Q(field1__isnull=False) | Q(field2__isnull=False) | Q(field3__isnull=False)

items = MyModel.objects.filter(f).exclude(**excl)
```

Comment: I think it should be f = Q(field1__isnull=False, field2__isnull=False) | Q(field3__isnull=False)

Comment: you are correct, assuming the SQL sample in the question is correct. But based on the wording of the question I'm led to believe it's a typo - see my note about danihp's comment.